# Sort List <Rectangle>

Tags: c#

How do I sort a rectangle list by their area? Been looking into IComparable at msdn library, but can't figure it out... I wrote this:

```
SortedL= new List<Rectangle>();
        int count1 = 0;
        int count3 = redovi;
        while (count1 < count3)
        {
            int count2 = 0;
            while (count2 < count3)
            {
                int x = Oblici[count1].Width;
                int y = Oblici[count1].Height;
                int z = Oblici[count2].Width;
                int w = Oblici[count2].Height;
                int area1 = x * y;
                int area2 = z * w;
                int a = area1.CompareTo(area2);
                if (a < 0)
                {
                    count1 = count2;
                    if (count2 < (count3 - 1))
                    {
                        count2++;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                else if (a == 0)
                {
                    if (count2 < (count3 - 1))
                    {
                        count2++;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                else if (a > 0)
                {
                    if (count2 < count3 - 1)
                    {
                        count2++;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
            }
            SortedL.Add(Oblici[count1]);
            Oblici.RemoveAt(count1);
            count3 = (count3 - 1);}}
```

And it works, but it's pretty ugly, and I know there is an easier way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this, using lambda expression to create your own Comparer

```
mylist.Sort((X, Y) => ((X.Height * X.Width).CompareTo(Y.Height * Y.Width)));
```

Comment: Good! The lambda creates a `Comparison<Rectangle>` delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can use LINQ, something like this ought to work:

```
var sortedList = Oblici.OrderBy(r => r.Width * r.Height).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's the long winded version that will help you get the other two.

Something like

```
private static int CompareByArea(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
   int a1 = r1.Width * r1.Height;
   int a2 = r2.Width * r2.Height;
   if (a1 < a2)
   {
      return - 1;
   }
   else
   {
     if (a1 > a2) 
     {
        return 1; 
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

then

```
MyList.Sort(CompareByArea)
```

A comparer for List is a static(usually) function that return -1,0,1 (less than, equal to or greater than by convention) from comparing two Ts somehow

Irritatingly obvious with a meaningful example isn't it. I read the technobabble first as well, sounded really complicated. :(

Comment: Eh? Even if it did get passed twice (CompareByArea(r1,r2)==1) && (CompareByArea(r2,r1)==1) isn't ever going to be true in the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this method to your `Rectangle` class:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
  if (obj == null) return 1;

  Rectangle otherRectangle = obj as Rectangle;

  if (otherRectangle != null)
    return this.Width * this.Height - obj.Width * obj.Height;
  else
    throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Rectangle");
}
```

That should allow you to compare two rectangles by area.

A `SortedList` of `Rectangle` should sort itself correctly, i.e. by area.  You need to derive `Rectangle` from `IComparable` to make everything follow along.